# how to insert long string oracle clob or blob

Tags: oracle, plsql

How I can insert very long text `100000 <length(string) < 300000` oracle clob or blob?

```
DECLARE
    v_long_text CLOB;
BEGIN
    v_long_text := 'my long string text';

    INSERT INTO MYTABLE_NAME 
    VALUES      (v_long_text);
END;
```

its metod is not worked, returned error `PLS-00172: string literal too long`

Comment: What is the datatype of column ?

Comment: I have both and does not matter which one will work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle 10: Using HEXTORAW to fill in blob data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116634/oracle-10-using-hextoraw-to-fill-in-blob-data)

Answer (score 8):

You literal is implicitly a varchar, so you are not able to assign to *v_long_text* value larger than maximum literal of varchar (maximum varchar length in plsql is 32767).

You can use concatenation:

```
DBMS_LOB.APPEND(v_long_text, 'very long string');
DBMS_LOB.APPEND(v_long_text, 'yet another long string');
```

Of course, I am assuming that MYTABLE_NAME column type is a CLOB

**UPDATE:**
Sample code:

```
DECLARE
    v_long_text CLOB;
BEGIN
   DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(v_long_text,true);
   DBMS_LOB.APPEND(v_long_text, dbms_random.string('U', 20000));
   DBMS_LOB.APPEND(v_long_text, dbms_random.string('U', 20000));
   DBMS_LOB.APPEND(v_long_text, dbms_random.string('U', 20000));
   DBMS_LOB.APPEND(v_long_text, dbms_random.string('U', 20000));
   DBMS_LOB.APPEND(v_long_text, dbms_random.string('U', 20000));
   DBMS_LOB.APPEND(v_long_text, dbms_random.string('U', 20000));
   DBMS_LOB.APPEND(v_long_text, dbms_random.string('U', 20000));

    INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (v_long_text);
END;
```

Comment: How Can I do that ? please write query simple

Comment: helped me a lot! 
this should be the best option

Answer (score 0):

Other approaches are good. But, if you have the long string stored somewhere in a file system, you could make use of these things.

- Load it using `SQL* loader` : This is easy and straightforward and
  can be automated to read from file system.
- Use unix `split` utility  with `-b` option  to split the long text in
  the file into smaller chunks ( say 32000 or 4000 ) and in a shell
  script construct multiple insert statements.

something like :

```
split -b 4000 yourbigfile split_files_
ct=1
for chunk in $(cat split_files_??)
 do
   # first time
   echo "INSERT INTO table_name(col_name) VALUES ('${chunk}');"
   # 2nd and subsequent
  echo " update table_name set col_name = col_name || '$chunk';"
  ct=$((ct + 1))
done >yourinsert_script.sql
```

- Create a PL/SQL procedure that reads the text from a file using
  `UTL_FILE` and inserts to the table.

Comment: Have you checked the solution?
In a similar case I've got an ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long.

Comment: @kunis : I'm not sure how you're doing it. As far as I remember it did work for me. It's possible that somewhere in your code you are concatenating literals who's total size exceeds 4000 chars

Comment: @nayak
`UPDATE "<table>" 
SET BK_DATASET_SQL = 'SELECT
SK_ACCNT_PUR_HIST_ID||''' || chr(38) || '3''|| ..... '
WHERE ...`

If the text that I'm going to put into BK_DATASET_SQL is too long (more then 4000 symbols), I'm getting
ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
    definition_clob CLOB;

BEGIN
dbms_lob.createtemporary(definition_clob, true);
dbms_lob.append(definition_clob,'String 1.. ">
dbms_lob.append(definition_clob,'String 2.. ">
.
.
.
INSERT INTO TABLE
(CLOB_COLUMN)
VALUES
(definition_clob)

COMMIT
dbms_lob.freetemporary(definition_clob);

END;
/
```