# Merging varchars into one CLOB

Tags: plsql, clob

I have the following procedure for merging 10 varchar variables of length 4000 characters into one CLOB:

```
  procedure insert_iec_by_parts(p_header_id in number,
                       p_contents_part1 in varchar2,
                       p_contents_part2 in varchar2,
                       p_contents_part3 in varchar2,
                       p_contents_part4 in varchar2,
                       p_contents_part5 in varchar2,
                       p_contents_part6 in varchar2,
                       p_contents_part7 in varchar2,
                       p_contents_part8 in varchar2,
                       p_contents_part9 in varchar2,
                       p_contents_part10 in varchar2,


                       o_cur_results out sys_refcursor,
                       result_code out number) is

l_clob clob;

begin

l_clob:=p_contents_part1||p_contents_part2||p_contents_part3||p_contents_part4||p_contents_part5||
        p_contents_part6||p_contents_part7||p_contents_part8||p_contents_part9||p_contents_part10;

insert_iec(p_header_id, l_clob, o_cur_results, result_code );

end;


  procedure insert_iec(p_header_id in number,
                       p_contents in clob,
                       o_cur_results out sys_refcursor,
                       result_code out number) is

    id_temp number;
    l_id number;

  procedure SetError(pErrCode number) is

  -- A centralised sub proc could allow for a quick change to raise_application_error at any time.

  begin

    result_code   := pErrCode;


  end;

  begin

  select count(*) into l_id from log_sync_calls_headers
where log_sync_calls_headers.id =p_header_id;

  case

    when (p_header_id is null) or (l_id <= 0)     then SetError(9804);
    when p_contents is null then SetError(9805);

        else

      -- fetch sequence number

   id_temp := iec_seq.nextval;

         result_code:=0;

      open o_cur_results for    
      select id_temp as id
      from dual;

           insert into log_sync_calls_iecs
       (id, header_id, contents)
       values
       (id_temp, p_header_id, p_contents );


      commit;
  end case;  

            exception      when others then
        result_code :=9701;
        rollback;
        pkg_common.insert_log_record(p_source => 'insert_iec',
                p_type => 'Er',
                p_message => sqlerrm);    



end;
```

Procedure works fine when merging 10 varchar variables of 4000 characters each. However, I want to extend it to 20 varchar variables of length 4000 characters.

When I try that, it gives me the following error:

```
ORA 06502: character string buffer too small.
```

Could someone show me how to be able to extend this procedure to 20 varchar variables of length 4000 characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DBMS_LOB.APPEND function like in this question (or just search for DBMS_LOB.APPEND in SO): [how to insert long string oracle clob or blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49816910/how-to-insert-long-string-oracle-clob-or-blob/49817056#49817056)

Comment: I have tried that, it gives me error: invalid LOB locator specified. Do you have an idea about how to solve this error?

Comment: I used DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(LINE,true); and now it works. Thank you.

Comment: @user11153823: Can you please accept the solution if it helped you move forward. thx. Every little bit counts :)

Comment: Could you explain to me the reversed process? How to split clob into varchar variables?

Comment: @user11153823: Why not open a question with this topic. I'm looking into anyway...

Comment: It's already anwered in this question by some very smart ppl: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647041/reading-clob-line-by-line-with-pl-sql

Comment: I don't have implementation of that procedure yet, so I think that I won't get answers. If you could explain that here, I would be very thankful.

Comment: That would mean the change the scope of the question, but have a look at the link above, it has plenty implementations of what your looking into.

Comment: I will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the `DBMS_LOB` package.

first you should create a clob object otherwise you variable is not initialized

```
dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_clob ,true);
```

now you can use `append` procedure

```
dbms_lob.append(l_clob, p_contents_part1 );
```

after you are finished , don't forget to release a clob Memory and destroy you clob object

```
dbms_lob.freetemporary(l_clob);
```